# Order the following cardinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

(1) $(\omega_2 \cdot \omega_1) + \omega_2$

(2) $2^{\omega_3}$

(3) $\omega_2+(\omega_1+\omega_3)$

(4) $ ( \omega_3 + \omega_1) + \omega_2$

(5) $\omega_1 +1$

I am not looking for an answer just some basic theorems about cardinal arithmetic and the standard way that one would approach this problem.

One approach is to find bijections to prove equality and a surjection to show inequality. However, such a process seems too lengthy. Is there an easier and more intuitive way to go about this problem?

Comment: Are the addition, multiplication and exponentiation ordinal or cardinal arithmetic?

Comment: @Asaf Cardinal arithmetic.

Comment: That's a bit strange, but okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** Recall that $\kappa+\lambda=\kappa\cdot\lambda=\max\{\kappa,\lambda\}$ for cardinal arithmetic (where at least one of the cardinals is infinite); and recall that $\kappa<2^\kappa$.

Comment: Do you know of any lecture notes or websites where I could find information regarding cardinal arithmetic similar to what you have given above?

Comment: Try googling: ["cardinal" {AND} "arithmetic" {AND} "notes" {AND} .pdf"](http://www.google.com/search?q=cardinal+arithmetic+notes+.pdf) I saw a lot of possibly useful items. All that I looked at included proofs and other verbal clutter that prevents it from being just a "fact sheet", but if that's what you want, you can easy type up your own using the notes from that search.

Comment: Well, these results are quite basic. Pretty much any course covering $\aleph$ numbers should have these. So pretty much any lecture notes or books I can think of. But beyond that, there's nothing more to cardinal arithmetic.